# Why does it give an install error when I download if from the Market but works perfectly when I manually install it?

Tags: android, installation, package, apk, google-play

I've finally managed to publish my first app on the Android Market. Unfortunately, when I try and download it, although it worked great on my phone, it says "Installation unsuccessful".

If I place it on my phone manually (on the SD Card or something) the app installs and boots up nicely.

I know this is a very large area where errors might be, but perhaps anyone's been through this  before and can give me a few tips of where to search.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed very much in need of a chrystal ball, but what can happen is that you have your test-apk still on your phone. (you did an unsigned debug version, just uploaded the non-market apk to your phone), and now it cannot install?

Remove all traces of your testing/debugging of your phone, or use a 'clean' phone

Comment: My friend, you are a true wizard. (Or a gipsy). Thanks a million...I was starting to panic.

Comment: I have gone trough this cycle several times. Install, test, upload, install, panic, remember, remove, install. :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I know this is a really noob thing, but I'm doing my best to learn all of these on my own :D